# Hiding html elements based on its child class jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have two forms(Login and register) in which one is hidden when the page is loaded(Login form is hidden). Users can toggle between them with a button. When login fails it throws a error and it is shown in login form. The issue is when the page is loaded after login fails it hides the login form and shows the Registers form. Only when the user clicks on login form button it shows the error. I want to show the form which has error when the page is reloaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#login_form').hide(); 
});
```

This is my login form

```
<form action="/login" method="post" id="login_form">
 {{csrf_field()}}

<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
<input type="text" name="email" id="login_email" placeholder="Email"/>
 @if ($errors->has('email'))
 <span class="help-block">
  <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
 </span>
 @endif
</div>

 <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
  <input type="password" name="password" id="login_pass" placeholder="Password"/>
  @if ($errors->has('password'))
 <span class="help-block">
  <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
 </span>
  @endif
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
   <input type="submit" class="btn" id="login_sbt_btn" value="Login"/>
  </div>

 </form>
```

The `help-block` gets added only when the error is there in the form

This works good but it hides all the form when the page is loaded first.

```
var $errorField = $('.has-error');      
if($errorField) {                      
    $('form').hide();                   
    $errorField.closest('form').show(); 
} else {
    $('#login_form').hide();            
}
```

Comment: Why not just move the error element outside both of the forms(same level as submit button)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` returns an array-like object. You have to check the `length` property like this:

```
var $errorField = $('.has-error');      
if($errorField.length != 0) {                      
    $('form').hide();                   
    $errorField.closest('form').show(); 
} else {
    $('#login_form').hide();            
}
```

Comment: @NaveenKumar `if($errorField)` will always be `true` (even if no elements were found). `$` will always return an object (an object is never falsy).